# Understanding capabilities of Twilio.

Tags: twilio

I'm trying to build a small application that will save an incoming phone number to the database and have a UI that will allow an administrator to send out blast messages to the numbers in the database. If anyone has experience with this I'd love some good documentation or advice on how to accomplish this task. If it is possible?

Comment: Twilio has good documentation. Something like this is dead easy -- you quite possibly could do this with a shell script and command line tools (like curl or wget). Example doc: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls

Comment: Note that each number you "buy" from Twilio is good for upto 1 call/ sec -- if you need more peak volume, you'll need to buy multiple numbers.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that John? I apologize I have never used Twilio before. Do you think you could explain that a bit deeper?

Comment: Not sure which part you want explained more.  The first part of using Twilio is obtaining one or more phone#s.  IIRC, they cost like $1/month each.  Each is rate limited to 1 call/sec (prob not an issue with voice calls), but it can be for SMS use.  To use Twilio you exchange messages via http/https -- it is a REST API and the content of these messages is a simple XML-like language they call TwilML.  The docs are quite good -- I was able to spin up an SMS-based password reset system in an afternoon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's some excerpts from my Twilio SMS app which might give you a sense of how you might interact with Twilio:

```
static const char *     sms_host        = "api.twilio.com";
static const char *     sms_user        = "AC(redacted)";
static const char *     sms_pass        = "(redacted)";
static const char *     sms_from        = "15155551212";  /* our purchased # */

static char * twilioSendTextUrl (
        void
) {
        return strBuild(NULL,
            "https://%s:%s@%s/2010-04-01/Accounts/%s/SMS/Messages",
            sms_user, sms_pass, sms_host, sms_user);
}

static char * twilioSendTextRequest (
        const char *    to,
        const char *    text
) {
        if ((to == NULL) || (text == NULL)) return NULL;
        return strBuild(NULL,
            "From=+%s"  "&"
            "To=+%s"    "&"
            "Body=%s",
            sms_from,
            to,
            cgiEncode(text)
        );
}

static char * doPost (
        const char *    url,
        const char *    postdata
) {
        CURL *  curl    = curl_easy_init();
        int     ces;

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, postdata);
        ...
        ces = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        ...
}

ret = doPost(twilioSendTextUrl(), twilioSendTextRequest(number, message));
```

Comment: Hi John, Megan from Twilio here. Thank you for helping out here in the StackOverflow community. I'd love to send you a shirt to say thanks! Email - mspeir@twilio.com.